# Passing javascript onclick parameter to an element on another page

Tags: javascript, forms, onclick, html-select

I've written a contact form that changes itself according to what's selected in a (form select option) dropdown at the top of the page, using some javascript to hide elements and change 'required' classes etc

This works fine on the page.

In the nav on the site, I have a dropdown (bootstrap 3) that mimics the options in the form dropdown. The idea being, visitors have 2 options to move to the form they want, either from the nav, or from the dropdown on the contact page.

I have some javascript that detect the nav selection and SHOULD change the associated dropdown on the contact page, this in fact works, provided you're already on the contact page.

The difficulty I'm having, is passing the value through to the contact page from, say the home page.

Some snippets below might help:

The contact page form dropdown:

```
   <div class="dropdown">
    <label for="nature">Nature of Enquiry?</label>
      <select tabindex=1 name="nature" id="nature">
       <option value="0" selected>Ask a Question</option>
       <option value="1">Get a Quote</option>
       <option value="2">Submit Meter Reading</option>
       <option value="3">Log a Service Call</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

The global nav:

```
   <li class="dropdown  <?=($page_title == 'Contact') ? 'active' : ''?>">
     <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Contact <b class="caret"></b></a>
     <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu choose">
       <li><a href="./contact.php#Contact" id="0">Ask a Question</a></li>
       <li><a href="./contact.php#Contact" id="1">Get a Quote</a></li>
       <li><a href="./contact.php#Contact" id="2">Submit Meter Reading</a></li>
       <li><a href="./contact.php#Contact" id="3">Log a Service Call</a></li>
     </ul>
   </li>
```

The global nav javascript catch:

```
<script>
  $('.choose a').click(function() {
    $('#nature').val(this.id).change();
  });
</script>
```

The local contact page javascript change function:

```
$('#nature').change(function() 
{ 
var selectedValue = parseInt(jQuery(this).val());

switch(selectedValue){
    case 0:
        hide('error');
        hide('clicks');
        show('subject');
        document.getElementById('subjectspan').style.display = 'inline'; 
        document.getElementById('companyspan').style.display = 'none'; 
        $('input#mono').removeClass('required'); 
        $('input#company').removeClass('required');
        $('textarea#message').addClass('required');                          
        break;
    case 1:
        hide('error');
        hide('clicks');
        show('subject');
        document.getElementById('subjectspan').style.display = 'inline'; 
        document.getElementById('companyspan').style.display = 'none'; 
        $('input#mono').removeClass('required'); 
        $('input#company').removeClass('required');
        $('textarea#message').addClass('required');                           
        break;
    case 2:
        hide('error');
        show('clicks');
        hide('subject');
        document.getElementById('companyspan').style.display = 'inline';
        document.getElementById('meterspan').style.display = 'inline';            
        document.getElementById('subjectspan').style.display = 'none'; 
        $('input#mono').addClass('required');
        $('input#company').addClass('required');
        $('textarea#message').removeClass('required');                        
        break;
    case 3:
        hide('error');
        hide('clicks');
        show('subject');
        document.getElementById('companyspan').style.display = 'inline';
        document.getElementById('subjectspan').style.display = 'inline'; 
        $('input#mono').removeClass('required');            
        $('input#company').addClass('required');
        $('textarea#message').addClass('required');            
        break;
}

});
```

I know that last bit of javascript is pretty untidy, but for now it works.

Like I say, the nav script works absolutely perfectly, provided you're already on the contact page. How can I get that to work from another page?

Comment: So when someone clicks `Get a Quote` you want it to go to the contact page and select that option by default? Just use a `GET` parameter. `<a href="contact.php?mode=ask-a-question">Ask a question</a>` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a GET parameter in the URL for the contact page, and then triggering your change event based on that.

The URL:

```
<li><a href="./contact.php?nature=0#Contact" id="0">Ask a Question</a></li>
```

The JavaScript on the contact page:

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    $('#nature').val(<?php echo $_GET['nature']; ?>).change();
  });
</script>
```

It would be a good idea to scrub the param first to prevent JavaScript injection.